# How to remove objects if there is no other relationships in Core Data to this object?

Tags: ios, core-data, entity-relationship

I have following entities in Core Data:

- `PBOUser` may have a lot of `PBOLocation`.
- `PBOLocation` may have a lot of `PBOStatistics`.
- `PBOStatistics` may belong to only one `PBOLocation`
- `PBOLocation` may belong to a lot of `PBOUser`

My relationship are described on the image below:
[image]

My problem:

I have `userA` with `locationA` and `locationB` and `locationC`
I have `userB` with `locationA` and `locationD`

Now inside `userA` I assign a new `NSSet` with `locationB`.

**What happens now?**

- Do I remove `locationC`? (I really want that, because this location belongs ONLY to user being removed)
- Do I remove `locationA`? (I really do not want that, because that location belongs to other user: `userB`).

What should I do to achieve that result?

Answer (score 1):

No locations are removed in described case, they just become orphaned.
You should fetch locations and manually delete it before assign new set or implement special method to delete all orphaned locations.

Comment: What about relationships: `nullify` i `cascade`?

Comment: It doesn't matter in this case. Cascade could be useful if you delete user object. In this case all related locations would be deleted.